# Can I get the name of the function outside the trigger itself?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I would like to get the name of the executing function at runtime. I want to add the function name when I store some data to the database like "this document was last modified by function 'xxx'". My function app has multiple functions that each can modify the same set of documents. The obvious idea would be to depend on `ExecutionContext`, but I can't get that when I am outside the trigger.

> The dependency injection container only holds explicitly registered types. The only services available as injectable types are what are setup in the Configure method. As a result, Functions-specific types like `BindingContext` and `ExecutionContext` aren't available during setup or as injectable types.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#caveats

I basically need the value of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext.FunctionName`.

```cs
    public class TriggerFunction
    {
        private readonly MyService myService;

        public TriggerFunction(MyService myService)
        {
            this.myService = myService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myService));
        }

        [FunctionName("TriggerFunction")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0/15 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            myService.Foo();
        }
    }

    public class MyService
    {
        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            // would be nice to have ExecutionContext here
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Foo");
            // How do I get "TriggerFunction" here without passing it explicitly as a parameter?
        }
        public ILogger<MyService> Logger { get; }
    }

    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }
    }
```

We are using .net core 3.1 running in-process.

Comment: Compile it in `public void Foo([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")`, if you check that parameter you will find the calling function name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-5.0

Comment: @TheGeneral this is quite the clever workaround. However it won't apply in my case since I am a bit deeper in the call tree and I need the value of the `FunctionName` attribute. Equivalent to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext.FunctionName`

Comment: Are you logging to Application Insights? If so, you can use the operationId to correlate the telemetry and know what function is involved

Comment: @TheGeneral The function name is set using an attribute. It does not have to match the name of the function in code.

Comment: @PeterBons I want to add the function name when I store some data to the database like a "last modified by this function".

Comment: A thought - you can define a service which is injected at scoped instance. At start of function, you can set the function name and down the execution tree, you can retrieve the name (from injected instance in the required class). Another thing, which you look for is `ITelemetryInitializer` it but I'm not sure, if it's possible to get the function name there too.

Answer (score 1):

One of your options is to use the `Activity` class. The Azure Function runtime uses it to track the operations / instrumentation. You can add your own information to this using `Activty.Current.AddBaggage`. Also, the information contained by the Activity flows with async calls within a process so it safe to use in task based scenario's as well.

```cs
    public class TriggerFunction
    {
        private readonly MyService myService;

        public TriggerFunction(MyService myService)
        {
            this.myService = myService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myService));
        }

        [FunctionName("TriggerFunction")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0/15 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            Activity.Current?.AddBaggage("functionName", context.FunctionName); 

            myService.Foo();
        }
    }

    public class MyService
    {
        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            // would be nice to have ExecutionContext here
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"Foo calling in Function { Activity.Current?.GetBaggageItem("functionName") }");
            // How do I get "TriggerFunction" here without passing it explicitly as a parameter?
        }
        public ILogger<MyService> Logger { get; }
    }

    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }
    }
```

For a deep dive into the `Activity` class see [this blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/)